# Naming convention of movie titles

Tags: title

I would like to know why most of the movie titles are in medial capitals? few examples like,

> [The Dark Knight](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0468569/)
>
> [He's Just Not That Into You](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1001508/)

I thought all the movie titles are medial capitalized but I've observed few titles like,

> [Out of the Furnace](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1206543/)

where middle two words are not medial capitalized, why?

Who decides the naming convention of movie titles?

Comment: The people that produce them, I guess. This is entirely up to the authors of the movie and thus a mere matter of taste or of cultural preference (for example small connective tissue like *"a"*, *"and"*, *"the"* or *"of"* seems to be preferred in small when not starting the title, at least in English). But there is no general institution guarding some convention (apart from maybe the "soft" law of marketability), I think, and this seems entirely up to the filmmakers' preference. (Yet I don't know it either, making this only a comment.)

Comment: napoleon's answer/comment is wrong.  In the US, at least.  See Darrick's answer for the correct one.

Comment: This is nothing specifically to do with films. This is just how titles work in English (as [Derrick's answer](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/18149/607) makes clear).

Comment: `The Dark Knight: He's Just Not That Into You` would be a movie I'd pay to see.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Fortunately it was just a comment. But could you still explain what in particular is wrong in my comment, as it seems in line with both answers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Movie titles typically use what is called [Title Case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Headings_and_publication_titles) for their names. This is a very common practice in the US for anything with a title (books, articles, headlines, movies, ... ).

Each production house has its own variation on which words to capitalize, but they are usually pretty standard with minor deviations. According to [grammer.About.com:](http://grammar.about.com/od/grammarfaq/f/capitalstitle.htm)

> Capitalize the first and last words of the title and all nouns, pronouns, adjectives, verbs, adverbs, and subordinating conjunctions (if, because, as, that, and so on): "Rules for Capitalizing the Words in a Title."
>
> It's the little words that style guides disagree on. The Chicago Manual of Style, for instance, notes that "articles (a, an, the), coordinating conjunctions (and, but, or, for, nor), and prepositions, regardless of length, are lowercased unless they are the first or last word of the title."
>
> But The Associated Press Stylebook is fussier:
>
> Capitalize the principal words, including prepositions and conjunctions of four or more letters.
> Capitalize an article--the, a, an--or words of fewer than four letters if it is the first or last word in a title.
> Other guides say that prepositions and conjunctions of fewer than five letters should be in lowercase--except at the beginning or end of a title. (For additional guidelines, see the glossary entry for title case.)
> So pick a form--any form. And then try to be consistent.

Answer (score 5):

Different grammatical rules are observed by different titles, often simply for the aesthetic choice.

## A a

Capitalized letters often appear visually bolder due to their comparative size.

Factor the consideration that font is something that is only controlled by officially licensed marketing material, and you can see why cramming in as much capitalization can make the title of the film 'pop' when written in print media; which may well explain the preference.

There is no explicit convention, its simply the result of what a creative team decides is most effective.

---

- Some films employ [Title Case](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/capital_letters_title_case.htm) capitalization, where the principal
  words are capitalized: After the initial word, short prepositions,
  articles and conjunctions are all lower case.
- Others go for Pascal Case, a derivative of [Camel Case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_case) where all
  the words are capitalized.

Comment: Camel case is used for compound words. "YouTube" is written in camel case; "The Dark Knight" and "Spider-Man" are not, because the words are still separated.

Comment: Hence the specification of 'Pascal Case', which is derived from Camel Case.

Comment: @nmclean, "YouTube" is PascalCase. "youTube" would be camelCase.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional No, they are synonyms, and they are specifically distinguished by a lack of spaces. Pascal Case refers to the programming language Pascal, where this style was used for multi-word names to work around the limitation that spaces were not allowed in names.

Comment: @BrianS Both versions are camel case (distinguished by "lower camel case" and "upper camel case").